# Start reading API response before content download is completed in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am calling API endpoint which returns large data which takes 1 minute and most time gets spent in Content Download phase. I am using rxjs observable with httpClient get method.

I dont want to wait until entire data is downloaded but rather start displaying data as it gets downloaded. If I use same url in Chrome browser it starts displaying data as it gets downloaded.

I have explored several options like fromFetch from rxjs and EventSource but none of it is seems relevant. Is there a way to achieve this in angular or rxjs?

Comment: You may want to look into lazy loading, if it suits your needs, for example if you want to display your data while scrolling down your page

Comment: As an option you can show some placeholders something like gray squares, similar how Youtube and Facebook do, until your data get downloaded. Or try to split your data into several endpoints and load them in parallel.